# C# Unexpected loop performance. Possible JIT bound check bug?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, jit

I noticed something odd when comparing the generated JIT of 2 methods which should perform the same.
To my surprise, the generated JIT had major differences and it's length was almost doubled for the supposedly simpler method M1.

The methods I compared were M1 and M2.
The number of assignments is the same, so the only difference should be how the bound checks are handled for each method.

```
using System;

public class C {
    static void M1(int[] left, int[] right)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            left[i] = 1;
            right[i] = 1;
        }
    }  
    
    static void M2(int[] left, int[] right)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i+=2)
        {
            left[i] = 1;
            right[i] = 1;
        }
    } 
}
```

Generated JIT for each method:

```
C.M1(Int32[], Int32[])
    L0000: sub rsp, 0x28
    L0004: xor eax, eax
    L0006: test rcx, rcx
    L0009: setne r8b
    L000d: movzx r8d, r8b
    L0011: test rdx, rdx
    L0014: setne r9b
    L0018: movzx r9d, r9b
    L001c: test r9d, r8d
    L001f: je short L005c
    L0021: cmp dword ptr [rcx+8], 5
    L0025: setge r8b
    L0029: movzx r8d, r8b
    L002d: cmp dword ptr [rdx+8], 5
    L0031: setge r9b
    L0035: movzx r9d, r9b
    L0039: test r9d, r8d
    L003c: je short L005c
    L003e: movsxd r8, eax
    L0041: mov dword ptr [rcx+r8*4+0x10], 1
    L004a: mov dword ptr [rdx+r8*4+0x10], 1
    L0053: inc eax
    L0055: cmp eax, 5
    L0058: jl short L003e
    L005a: jmp short L0082
    L005c: cmp eax, [rcx+8]
    L005f: jae short L0087
    L0061: movsxd r8, eax
    L0064: mov dword ptr [rcx+r8*4+0x10], 1
    L006d: cmp eax, [rdx+8]
    L0070: jae short L0087
    L0072: mov dword ptr [rdx+r8*4+0x10], 1
    L007b: inc eax
    L007d: cmp eax, 5
    L0080: jl short L005c
    L0082: add rsp, 0x28
    L0086: ret
    L0087: call 0x00007ffc50fafc00
    L008c: int3

C.M2(Int32[], Int32[])
    L0000: sub rsp, 0x28
    L0004: xor eax, eax
    L0006: mov r8d, [rcx+8]
    L000a: cmp eax, r8d
    L000d: jae short L0036
    L000f: movsxd r9, eax
    L0012: mov dword ptr [rcx+r9*4+0x10], 1
    L001b: cmp eax, [rdx+8]
    L001e: jae short L0036
    L0020: mov dword ptr [rdx+r9*4+0x10], 1
    L0029: add eax, 2
    L002c: cmp eax, 0xa
    L002f: jl short L000a
    L0031: add rsp, 0x28
    L0035: ret
    L0036: call 0x00007ffc50fafc00
    L003b: int3
```

M1's length is double of M2's!

What could explain this and is it some kind of bug?

**EDIT**

Figured out that M1 creates a version for the loop without bound checks, and that's why M1 is longer. Still the question remains, Why M1 performs worse, even though it doesn't perform bound checking at all?

---

I also ran BenchmarkDotNet and verified that M2 performs about 20% - 30% faster than M1 for arrays of length 10

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.1, OS=Windows 10.0.14393.3930 (1607/AnniversaryUpdate/Redstone1)
Intel Core i7-4790 CPU 3.60GHz (Haswell), 1 CPU, 8 logical and 4 physical cores
Frequency=3515622 Hz, Resolution=284.4447 ns, Timer=TSC
.NET Core SDK=3.1.401
  [Host]     : .NET Core 3.1.7 (CoreCLR 4.700.20.36602, CoreFX 4.700.20.37001), X64 RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 3.1.7 (CoreCLR 4.700.20.36602, CoreFX 4.700.20.37001), X64 RyuJIT


|  Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev | Ratio |
|-------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|------:|
| M1Bench | 4.372 ns | 0.0215 ns | 0.0201 ns |  1.00 |
| M2Bench | 3.350 ns | 0.0340 ns | 0.0301 ns |  0.77 |
```

Comment: _"Why M1 performs worse, even though it doesn't perform bound checking at all?"_ -- you didn't provide a [mcve], so it's impossible to say for sure. But, there's a lot of overhead up front for `M1()` to know it can use the "fast" path...if your arrays aren't large enough, the overhead would dominate and produce counter-intuitive results.

Comment: Too few loop iterations, test with ~500k iterations, the resilt will be more respective then.

Comment: When I test the two versions there is little if any difference.

Comment: I tried this and I can reproduce the results for small arrays - but I also tried larger arrays and M1 gradually gets faster and faster in comparison to M2.  At N=50,000, M1 is 50% faster than M2.

Comment: Added your example to the tracking issue for loop cloning in RyuJit: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/8558

Answer (score 1):

> But, there's a lot of overhead up front for M1() to know it can use
> the "fast" path...if your arrays aren't large enough, the overhead
> would dominate and produce counter-intuitive results.

Peter Duniho

The overhead of choosing the path (in the JIT) for optimized bound check with loops of type:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
```

won't be beneficial for smaller loops.

As loops grow larger, eliminating bound checks becomes more beneficial, and surpasses the performance of a non-optimized path.

examples for non optimized loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i+=2)
for(int i = 0; i <= array.Length; i++)
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length / 2; i++)
```